# Find the length of the common chord $PQ$

Tags: geometry, circles

Two circles with centres $O$ and $O \ '$ of radii $3$  cm and $4$  cm, respectively intersect at two points $P$ and $Q$ such that $OP$ and $O \ 'P$ are two tangents to the two circles. Find the length of the common chord $PQ$.

Here's the figure:

[image]

I have done the following:

> $\angle OQO \ ' = \angle OPO \ ' = 90 ^{\circ}$
>
> Also line joining the centres is perpendicular to the common chord.
>
> Since $ \angle OPO \ ' =  90 ^{\circ}$, therefore, in $\Delta OPO \ ' , \ OO \ ' = 5 \ cm$ (by pythagoras theorem)

But I couldn't do it further.

Answer (score 2):

$OPO'$ is a right angled triangle.

**Hint:** What is the area of triangle $OPO'$?

**Hint:** Let $PQ$ intersect $OO'$ at $S$.  Consider $PS$ as the height of triangle $OPO'$, what is the length of $PS$?

Comment: thnx was far too easy than I was thinking